# Check if a specific value appears more than once in a table with a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I tried with this but it is not what I want :

```
var result = myList
    .GetQueryable()
    .GroupBy(g => g.Name)
    .Where(w => w.Name == "myName")
    .AnyAsync(a => a.Count() > 1);
```

This should return `true` if it finds *more then 1 record* with the name `"myName"` and `false` if at most one name `"myName"` is found.

I get **compile time error** in the `Where` clause. But I need to check for a specific value.

Any idea?

Comment: `var result = myList.Where(item => item.Name == "myName").Skip(1).Any();` id you want to check if `myList` contains *at least* `2` items with `Name` `"myName"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need in `GroupBy` (which will group the *entire* `myList`) and in `Count()` (if we have, say, `123456789` `"myName"` items then `Count()` will count them *all* and only then compare with `1`):

```
var result = myList
  .Where(item => item.Name == "myName") // items of interest only
  .Skip(1)                              // Skip the first one
  .Any();                               // do we have second?
```

we filter items of interest: `Where`, `Skip` the very *first* of them and check if we have *second* one.

Comment: This workes, but I had to add a OrderBy after the Where clause. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
bool result = (myList.Where(item => item.Name == "myName").Count() > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var differentNames = myList.Select(l => l.name == "myName")
                              .Distinct()
                              .Count();

  var res = differentNames >= 2;
```